# AutoIt DllCall to USB

Tags: dll, usb, autoit

I am having trouble with AutoIt's DLLCall.

I am trying to control a Delcom USB Indicator LED Light using AutoIT. To do this, I have a .dll which includes the following functions:

DelcomGetDeviceCount: returns the number of Delcom USB devices

DelcomGetNthDevice: searches for specified device type, gets string of device name

DelcomOpenDevice: takes device name and returns handle to the USB device

DelcomLEDControl: takes USB handle, sets state of the LED

Here is [a link](http://www.delcom-eng.com/downloads/delcomdllmanual.pdf) to the documentation on these DLL functions.

I think my problem is not formatting the pointer to the device name correctly, because my call to DelcomGetNthDevice returns 0, failure to find device, even though I detect one device using DelcomGetDeviceCount.

I have tried

```
Local $handleDLL = DLLOpen("C:\DelcomDLL.dll")
Local $stString = DllStructCreate("wchar Name[512]")

Local $devices = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomGetDeviceCount","dword",0)

Local $result = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomGetNthDevice","dword",1,"dword",0,"ptr",DllStructGetPtr($stString))

Local $handleUSB = DllCall($handleDLL,"handle","DelcomOpenDevice","str",DllStructGetData($stString,"Name"),"dword",0)
Local $result2 = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomLEDControl","handle",$handleUSB[0],"dword",0,"dword",1)


MsgBox(0,"# of Devices",$devices[0])
MsgBox(0,"Bool Found Device",$result[0])

DllClose($handleDLL)
```

and

```
Local $handleDLL = DLLOpen("C:\Users\b46020\Documents\Asher Project\DelcomDLL.dll")
Local $stString

Local $devices = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomGetDeviceCount","dword",0)

Local $result = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomGetNthDevice","dword",1,"dword",0,"str*",$stString)

Local $handleUSB = DllCall($handleDLL,"handle","DelcomOpenDevice","str*",$stString,"dword",0)
Local $result2 = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomLEDControl","handle",$handleUSB[0],"dword",0,"dword",1)


MsgBox(0,"# of Devices",$devices[0])
MsgBox(0,"Bool Found Device",$result[0])

DllClose($handleDLL)
```

but in each case I turn up 1 device but cannot get its name.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: Two things appear wrong in the first example, you are mixing wchar[] and str, which are very different types (though AutoIt should do the conversion for you in this case). I'll need a link to the header file to check this, but it looks like you are passing a pointer to a string, rather than an array of pointers to strings. I quickly wrote what I think should be able to give you the names of all the devices, but of course I cannot test it: https://gist.github.com/MattDiesel/5862545

Comment: Yes thanks Matt, I changed the device name to char[] and it worked.

Comment: Good to see you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
Local $handleDLL = DllOpen("C:\DelcomDLL.dll")

$strName = DllStructCreate("char Name[512]")
$ptrName = DllStructGetPtr($strName)

Local $result = DllCall($handleDLL, "dword", "DelcomGetNthDevice", "dword", 0, "dword", 0, "ptr", $ptrName)
Local $handleUSB = DllCall($handleDLL, "handle", "DelcomOpenDevice", "str", DllStructGetData($strName, "Name"), "dword", 0)
Local $result2 = DllCall($handleDLL, "dword", "DelcomLEDControl", "handle", $handleUSB[0], "dword", $color, "dword", $state)

Local $closed = DllCall($handleDLL,"dword","DelcomCloseDevice","handle",$handleUSB[0])
DllClose($handleDLL)
```